# How to structure web pages

Tags: html, iis, web, asp-classic

What's the technique behind when pages on a website is structured like this? example.com/pages/about

When looking in the code behind it is obvious that page in question is actually placed in the root (example.com) and furthermore it is possible append anything to the URL (like example.com/pages/about/qwerty) and yet it still returns the correct page?

I simply don't know what to google for.

---

I forgot to mention, that I work in classic ASP. It turned out that 'semantic URL' was what I was looking for. To make up for my 'thumbs down' for lack of research, here's a solution that I came up with this morning:

example.com/about/default.asp:

```
<%session("jump")="about.asp"
response.redirect "http://example.com"%>
```

example.com/default.asp should include:

```
<%if len(session("jump"))>0 then server.transfer(session("jump"))%>
```

This will make the semantic URL example.com/about useable and will not present the user with the URL of the resulting page: example.com/about.asp

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller

Comment: They are most likely using some kind of routing engine. There are many out there and it's impossible to tell just from that url. For example Microsoft has their implementation with ASP.Net MVC , Java has Spring MVC. PHP has codeigniter (and tons of others)

Comment: Check this out regarding query strings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

This link explains how ASP.NET handles routing as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Generally you'll want to decide on web framework and work on the routing from there though.

Answer (score 2):

You're using Classic ASP, which doesn't have any established MVC framework, so MVC routing probably isn't going to be much help to you.  What you should probably google for is "URL Rewriting".  There's a pure ASP solution which involves creating a custom 404 page and using `server.transfer` within conditional statements (so you were starting to think along the right lines), but from a practical point of view what you probably want to use is the IIS URL Rewrite Module.

First of all you need to be using IIS7 or later, which I think we can safely assume now you will be, given that the Microsoft no longer supports OSs which had an earlier version.  You can add rules either through IIS manager or by adding them directly to your web.config file.  For example, if you wanted example.com/about to take you to about.asp, and example.com/contact to take you to contact.asp (both files in your root directory) then you would add the following to the `<system.webServer>` section of your web.config file

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>            
        <rule name="About" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^about$"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="about.asp"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Contact" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^contact$"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="contact.asp"/>
        </rule>            
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

There's a good tutorial on Microsoft's IIS website:

https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module